# Streaming files directly to Client from Amazon S3 (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, sails.js

I am using sails.js and am trying to stream files from the Amazon s3 server directly to the client.

To connect to S3, I use the s3 Module : https://www.npmjs.org/package/s3
This module provides capabilities like `client.downloadFile(params)` and `client.downloadBuffer(s3Params)`.

My current code looks like the following:

```
var view = client.downloadBuffer(params);
view.on('error', function(err) {
    cb({success: 0, message: 'Could not open file.'}, null);
});
view.on('end', function(buffer) {
    cb(null, buffer);
});
```

I catch this buffer in a controller using:

```
User.showImage( params , function (err, buffer){
    // this is where I can get the buffer
});
```

Is it possible to stream this data as an image file (using `buffer.pipe(res)` doesn't work of course). But is there something similar to completely avoid saving file to server disk first?

The other option `client.downloadFile(params)` requires a local path (i.e. a server path in our case)

Comment: You'll need to figure out where the S3 link is to your data, usually in the form of `bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/file`. Then from there you can either directly access a public file, or you can implement a way of accessing private files (hopefully someone knows where there's documentation on that)

Comment: @ZekeSonxx I already know the path. I am actually trying to mask the path

Answer (score 1):

The GitHub issue contains the "official" answer to this question: https://github.com/andrewrk/node-s3-client/issues/53

Comment: Yup I have replied to your response too.